# Django: Data uownership for users

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am trying to create a simple app. It has the following model:

**Model: Product**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_owner = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='User')
    product_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, 
verbose_name='Product title')
    product_description = models.TextField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Product description')
    product_qty = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Quantity')
    product_mrp = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, verbose_name='Maximum retail price')

    product_sku = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, unique=True, verbose_name='SKU',help_text='Enter Product Stock Keeping Unit')
    product_barcode = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, verbose_name='Barcode')
```

I am using only the built in Admin App provided by django framework. And I was able to Make the Product data availaible for only the respective user by adding the following in the Admin classes.

```
class ProductAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('product_owner',)
    list_display = ['product_title','product_description', 'product_qty', 
                   'product_mrp','product_sku','product_barcode']
    search_fields = ['product_title', 'product_description', 'product_sku', 
                    'product_barcode']
    ordering = ['id']
    list_display_links = ['product_title']

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return Product.objects.all()
        return Product.objects.filter(product_owner=request.user)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not change:
            obj.product_owner = request.user
        obj.save()
```

As I just started experimenting, I added 2 users, User1 and User2. 
For User1 I added 10 products. Then I loggen in as User2 and User2 cannot see the products added by User1.

Now when I am tying to add products for User2, and if there is a conflict in product_sku field which is a unique field, I cannot add the product at all.

How to solve this. I need each user to add his own products, but product_sku unique to his set of products data, not for the whole database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of defining `unique=True` on the `product_sku` field, you should define [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#unique-together) for sku and user.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('product_sku', 'product_owner'),)
```

This will ensure that each user can only have one product with a particular sku, but multiple users can have the same sku.